# Cakephp: Passing in page count to PaginatorHelper

Tags: cakephp, pagination, view-helpers

I'd like to pass in the pageCount instead of have the PaginatorHelper class get it off the model. The reason is that I'm not using the model at all.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You should always mention the exact CakePHP version you are using. This is vital for a correct answer. See the answer below (which would only work for current master - 2.4 - and above).

Comment: I'm using the latest version i.e. 2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally the params are stored in `$this->request->params['paging'][$model]`, where $model is the name of the desired model. The exact data in this variable can be found in the [Cake docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper%3a%3aparams). You will always need a name of a model, but you can make one up.

In your controller:

```
$this->request->params['paging']['MyModel'] = array(
   'pageCount' => 3
);
```

In your view:

```
$this->Paginator->param('pageCount', 'MyModel');
```

Comment: It should be noted that I added this method in CakePHP2.4 :) So anyone before that needs to use the params() method and manually extract pageCount then.